# Difference between annotation and request object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to ask if there is a difference between the annotation [FromForm] and Request.Form. Is there a difference in the way they access the Request object? For reference this is the code

```
public IActionResult Test ([FromForm] IFormFile File1)
{
      var File2 = Request.Form.File[0];
}
```

If there is a difference then how do you send the file in case of [FromForm] from a angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [FromForm] annotation merely tells the compiler that the value for argument "File1" should come from the request object's "form".
2. Here is the documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding
>
> - FromQuery - Gets values from the query string.
> - FromRoute - Gets values from route data.
> - FromForm - Gets values from posted form fields.
> - FromBody - Gets values from the request body.
> - FromHeader - Gets values from HTTP headers.

3. Your action handler, "Test()", has "File1" as a parameter.

   But "Test()" should also be able to read "File1" from the Request.Form object.

   Different "abstractions" - same thing.

Comment: So there is no difference in the way an angular app sends a file?

Comment: Short answer: "No" - it's all HTTP.  Having said that: there are different ways you can send the file (at the HTTP level), and there are different "abstractions" you can choose from (at the C#/ASP.Net and JS/Angular app levels).  This article might help: https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/